# GCR Image Tag Listing using GCloud SDK CLI

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

I'm trying to get list of all the tags in my private GCR repository. I could do that using "*gcloud container images list-tags*" command as follows:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/REPONAME

DIGEST        TAGS          TIMESTAMP
6b5727be962a  0.0.4,latest  2020-06-25T14:14:48
4b8c3f9c6ab7  0.0.3         2020-06-22T08:56:01
```

However I need the list to be flatten so that i can get tags "0.0.4" and "latest" in separate rows. I tried following command.

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/REPONAME --flatten='[].tags'
```

This gave me output which is to my surprise repeating "*latest*" tag but ommiting "*0.0.4*"

```
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
6b5727be962a  latest  2020-06-25T14:14:48
6b5727be962a  latest  2020-06-25T14:14:48
4b8c3f9c6ab7  0.0.3   2020-06-22T08:56:01
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to repro your observation and think it's a bug.

The `--flatten` appears to correctly enumerate `tags` but incorrectly returns the last value in the list as each entry's value.

In my case, if the tags are `v1,v2,v3`, I get:

```sh
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE} \
--flatten="[].tags[]" \
--format="value(tags)" \
--filter="digest=${DIGEST}"
v3
v3
v3
```

I recommend you file a bug on Google's Issue Tracker for [`Cloud SDK`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102)

#### jq

If you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), perhaps:

```sh
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE} \
--format=json |\
 jq -r '.[] | .digest as $D | .timestamp.datetime as $T | .tags[]| {"digest":$D,"tag":.,"timestamp":$T}'
```

Or:

```sh
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE} \
--format=json |\
 jq -r '.[] | .digest as $D | .timestamp.datetime as $T | .tags[]| [$D,.,$T] | @csv'
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs. I've opened issue on GCloud SDK issue tracker as per your suggestion, [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161399034) lets see.

Comment: Update: @DazWilkin
Google has is fixed this issue and it is scheduled to be part of GCloud SDK version 325.0.0 set to be released on Tuesday, January 26 2021.