# How to get a specific tag from Google GCR with regex using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I'm tagging my images with git_short_sha and branch_name and some other tags. I'm trying to get the short_sha tag of the image tagged with master using a gcloud command.
I've managed to get all tags, or a specific tag by its' location with these commands:

```
1. gcloud container images list-tags eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE} --format='value(tags[1])' --filter="tags=master"

result:
76f1a2a
```

but I cannot be sure that the second element will always be the short_sha.

```
 2. gcloud container images list-tags eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE} --format='value(tags)' --filter="tags=master"

result:
1.0.0-master,76f1a2a,76f1a2a-master,master
```

Is it possible to get only the short_sha tag by using only gcloud command?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```sh
gcloud container images list-tags eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE} \
--flatten="[].tags[]" \
--filter="tags=${TAG}"
```

This came up once [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919234/609290). If you encounter that bug, you can try the `jq` solution.